# How do I get a table as output instead of a list when using the table-function and one of my factors is missing a level?

Tags: r, missing-data

I am processing the results of a questionnaire and want to present the responses on several related Yes/No questions in one single table. On one of these questions all respondents answered "No". It appears that as a result of missing one response level in this question, the table-function in R returns a list instead of a table.

Adding factor level "Yes" to the question with zero "Yes" responses, does not solve the problem. The code I present below, by the way, works fine for questions where respondents answered either "Yes" or "No".

This code relates to three questions answered by five respondents and illustrates my questionnaire.

```
q1 <- c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")
q2 <- c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No") # our culprit
q3 <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")
```

From this data I wish to create the following table:

```
     q1  q2  q3
Yes   4   0   2
No    1   5   3
```

Realizing that factor q2 has only one level I wrote:

```
q2 <- factor(q2, levels = c("Yes", "No"))
```

I combine the question vectors in a dataframe and apply the table-function to its columns:

```
df <- data.frame(q1, q2, q3)
apply(df, 2, table)
```

The actual output of the table-function is not the table above but the list below:

```
$q1

 No Yes 
  1   4 

$q2

No 
 5 

$q3

 No Yes 
  3   2
```

Comment: If you create your df by using the parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, then you can do `table(stack(df))`.

Comment: you also can change your apply to `lapply(df, table)` and get the 0's for Yes

Comment: also fyi `apply` converts factors to characters that is why you are having the problem above. Run these two and see what the output is: `lapply(df, class)`  , `apply(df, 2, class)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to me that the apply-function converts factors to characters. Solution in your first comment returns the answer suggested by @Onyambu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to explicitly list the labels across all the values you want to measure. Then you can convert to factor and do the sum

```
vals <- c("Yes", "No")
df <- data.frame(q1, q2, q3)
sapply(lapply(df, factor, levels=vals), table)
```

Here the inner `lapply` creates the factors with the proper levels for all lists, and the `sapply` runs the `table()`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can count each grouping then use `fill=0` when spreading to get the desired table.

```r
df %>% gather(k,v) %>% 
  count(k,v) %>% spread(k,n,fill=0)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  v        q1    q2    q3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 No        1     5     3
2 Yes       4     0     2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table(stack(list(q1=q1,q2=q2,q3=q3)))

      ind
values q1 q2 q3
   No   1  5  3
   Yes  4  0  2
```